# Playing Video Playlist

Tags: android

I have done a project on playing of m3u8 videolist in android.But the problem is that only a black screen is showing on running the project.How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Sometime black screen occurs if you are doing some synchronous tasks before the setContentView, let say you are trying to playing the video in full screen,if you are hiding the notification bar before setContentView in the videoPlay activity then it will cause black screen problem.  Solution is to process time consuming process asynchronously if there are any, secondly setting the contentView first of all before doing any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with setting **content view**. Open your Manifest file and check what is the launcher activity. Now open source code of launcher activity probably check what is the view that you are setting

**example:** if you have used `setContentView(R.layout.main);` open
   main.xml layout file in GraphicalLayout Editor to see what is the
   view that you have set. Make sure you have adde view correctly.